# How to Center and Right-align on a row with CSS Flex only

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Tried many variations like this, but could not get it to work. Here is the last attempt:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  //justify-content: center;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: yellow
}
.c {
  //flex: 1 1 0;
  //text-align: end;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: cyan;
}  
.e {
  //flex: 1 1 0;
  // text-align: end;
  background-color: grey;
}  
.bs {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  width: 70px;
}
```

with html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="c">
    <button class="bs">OK</button>
    <button class="bs">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  <div class="e">
    <button class="bs">Help</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know how to solve this by placing a 'visibility: hidden' button on the left-hand side and use justify-content with space-between, but I want to learn/know how to do it using CSS only.

Would be grateful for advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one way to do that.

Here with CSS only (no extra markup/hidden element) using a pseudo and make it and each *button wrapper* take 1/3 each of the total width, by giving them `flex-basis: 100%` and then the default `flex-shrink: 1` will shrink them equally.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: yellow
}
.parent::before, .c, .e {
  content: '';
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
.c {
  background-color: cyan;
  text-align: center;
}  
.e {
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: right;
}  
.bs {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="c">
    <button class="bs">OK</button>
    <button class="bs">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  <div class="e">
    <button class="bs">Help</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

The above solution is based on the answer I gave here:

- [How to align groups of buttons on single row with Flex only?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45679578/2827823)

And here is 3 more ways, where the first sample also solve this without any extra markup using absolute positioning

- [Center and right align flexbox elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948102/center-and-right-align-flexbox-elements)

Answer (score 2):

If you want it perfectly aligned, you can add an empty child `div` and split the three child `div`s into thirds.

This will work: **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/brLKeP)**

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.parent div {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
}

.c {
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.e {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: grey;
}

.bs {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="c">
    <button class="bs">OK</button>
    <button class="bs">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  <div class="e">
    <button class="bs">Help</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** If you want the buttons to be the same size, you can add `flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);` to your `.bs` class in the code above.

You might want to add horizontal margin on the center buttons as well.

---

You can also create an empty child `div` and call `justify-content: space-between` on the parent container, but it won't be perfectly aligned:  **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/jLZKwb)**, or use the snippet below.

---

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.bs {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div></div>
  <div class="c">
    <button class="bs">OK</button>
    <button class="bs">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  <div class="e">
    <button class="bs">Help</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: second example worked good

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent00_100perc, .parent01_100perc {
  display: flex;
  width: 480px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.parent00_100perc::before {
  content: '';
  flex: 0 0 100%; 
}
.parent01_100perc::before {
  content: '';
  flex: 0 1 100%; 
}


.spanflex00 { flex: 0 0 100%;}
.spanflex01 { flex: 0 1 100%;}

.bs {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  width: 70px;
}
.itemcenter {
  background-color: cyan;
  text-align: center;
}
.itemright {
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<p>Solution is by LGSon. I have just added a bit to verify I understand it by showing the initialisation and shrinkage phases of the solution, i.e.</p>

<p>Phase 1. initialisation that produces three parts of equal size on a single line. From left to right an empty part, a mid part with centred OK and Cancel buttons and a last part with a right-aligned Help button. Size of line 3x480px and is shown.</p>

<p>Phase 2. init & shrinkage that removes equal amount of space on the left and between the mid and right buttons. This leaves the OK and Cancel buttons still centred and shows a 480px wide result>


<p>Phase 1: after initialsation 0 0 100%</p> 
<div class="parent00_100perc">
  <span class="spanflex00 itemcenter">
    <button class="bs">OKAY</button>
    <button class="bs">Kancel</button>
  </span>
  <span class="spanflex00 itemright">
    <button class="bs">SOS</button>
  </span>
</div>

<p>Phase 2: init and shrinking 0 1 100%</p> 
<div class="parent01_100perc">
  <span class="spanflex01 itemcenter">
    <button class="bs">OK</button>
    <button class="bs">Cancel</button>
  </span>
  <span class="spanflex01 itemright">
    <button class="bs">Help</button>
  </span>
</div>

<p>This method/solution can create a centred mid-part with one or two edge parts without adding empty divs or hidden elements to one of the edges.
```